# want to redirect particular wildcard url permanently to some domain url. So i need .htaccess Rules for this can anyone help me with this

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

When I open below url need to permanent redirect url:

```
xyz.domain.com/category_product/air-freshener-refill/77/158
```

Permanent redirect and show data as per this url:

```
domain.com.au/category_product/air-freshener-refill/77/158
```

I want to write `.htaccess` rules for above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this rule in top of xyz.domain.com .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # www and non www xyz.domain.com/any to http://domain.com.au/any
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xyz\.domain\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is this method still works if i want to stay on same page but show data of https://domain.com.au/$1 this domin.
Note:- xyz.domain.com.au is http where as domin.com.au is https

Comment: if both websites are http then i have used this and it worked:-
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com\.au
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dev.domain.com.au/some_page_url/%1 [P,NC,QSA]

Now i am using same code but xyz.domain.com is http where as other is https for that i have use this code:-

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com\.au
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com.au/supplier_website/%1 [P,NC,QSA]

but this one not worked